# How to align Lightning:Textarea with other Lightning:Input fields

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

[image]

component Code:

```html
<div class="slds-grid slds-gutters "> 
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-8">  
      <label class="slds-text-title_bold">
      Monthly internal financial statements
      </label>                       
    </div>                     
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-8"> 
      <lightning:button label="Upload" class="slds-button" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.UploadPLDocuments}"></lightning:button> 
    </div> 
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12"> 
      <lightning:input type="checkbox" name="input1" labelVisible="false"/>
    </div> 
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-8"> 
      <lightning:textarea aura:id="txtnotes" value="" maxlength="5000"/>                                  
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your textarea have a `variant` of `label-hidden` eg

```
<lightning:textarea aura:id="txtnotes" 
                    variant="label-hidden" 
                    value="" 
                    maxlength="5000"/>
```

This will mean that the label, which is empty, won't be rendered and take up space.

Comment: Thanks a lot Caspar. It worked.

Comment: If it worked for you, you can upvote and mark as accepted.